# Sophie Germain's Theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am working on a small assignment on Sophie Germain's theorem for my *elementary* number theory class, for which I have to write up an original problem and its solution. The theorem itself goes like this:

> Let $p$ be an odd prime and assume that $2p+1$ is a prime. Let $x, y, z$ be integers such that $x^p + y^p = z^p$. Then $p$ divides at least one of the integers $x, y$ or $z$.

I have been researching the internet left and right and consulting many textbooks, but I could not find any idea. Here is therefore my specific question:

> Do you have any idea, suggestion, hint or link that might help me coming up with at least problem that deals directly with Sophie Germain's theorem?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: See also [here](https://www.agnesscott.edu/lriddle/women/germain-FLT/SGandFLT.htm), for a good summary with a lot of references.

Comment: Another useful references is [this one](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/courses/12-13/nt/projects/Colleen-Alkalay-Houlihan.pdf). Section $3$ proves the theorem you want.

Comment: Maybe the Fermat near misses? For example, $21^4 + 36^4 + 37^4 = 44^4 + 162$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A detailed proof of Sophie Germain's (weak) Theorem can be found in the lecture notes of B. Sury [here](http://www.isibang.ac.in/~sury/afsant.pdf), on page $2$. It is quite elementary and more or less only uses Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Thanks for this response,  as well as your two comments! Thanks again.

Comment: Here goes the green check mark! Thanks Dietrich Bunde.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain%27s_theorem) gives a different problem descriptiopin, and a useful application by Legendre in the History section

Comment: It is not different, but just stronger. Her theorem is usually stated in a weaker form, as above. See section $3$ [here](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/courses/12-13/nt/projects/Colleen-Alkalay-Houlihan.pdf).